# RAID1はバックアップにはならないですか？

Tags: ハードウェア

2TBの外付けHDD1台にメディアファイルを保存しています
過去にHDDの故障でデータを紛失した経験があり外付けHDDが1台故障したとしても復旧できるようにバックアップしたいと考えました

調べるとRAID1という方法を知りましたがRAID1はバックアップにならないという記事を見かけ不安になったため質問した次第です
記事には下にように書かれており、これを私は「データは2つのHDDで同期されるからもう片方のデータが失われればそれがもう片方にも反映される。つまりバックアップにはならない」ということだと把握しました

上の調査を元に質問があるのですが、RAID1は何等かの原因で片方のHDDが故障してデータが破損した時に、もう片方のHDDにも壊れたデータが同期されてしまうのでしょうか？
私はHDDの故障に対してのバックアップが欲しいと考えてるのですがRAID1ではバックアップになりませんか？

https://pasokon110.com/data/sp2019032809/#outline__4_1

> RAID1自体は“バックアップ”ではない
>
> RAID1は同じデータの複製＝ミラーリングになっているので、「ここに保存しておけばバックアップは完璧！」と、思われるかもしれません。しかし、実際にはHDD1と2にそれぞれ同じデータが“同時に”保存されます。データを間違えて上書き保存し足り消してしまった場合、同時に上書きされるので「間違えたからバックアップから戻す」ということはできません。つまり、バックアップとしては機能しないということになります。

Comment: 参考記事で言いたいのは”「間違えたからバックアップから戻す」ということは出来ない”ということかと思います。故障時のバックアップとしては有効でしょう。　※サーバー運用経験は無いのでコメントに留めさせてもらいます。

Comment: @merinoさん：コメントありがとうございます。私もそのように解釈したのですがもしHDDの片方が故障しデータが破損するともう片方にも破損したデータがコピーされてしまうのか？（頂いたコメントの言葉をお借りすると「HDDが"間違えてしまう"ことはあるのか？」）という疑問が残り質問に至った次第です

Comment: 質問に対する答えではありませんが、HDDの状態をこまめにチェックしてエラーが発生している場合は早めに対策することが重要かと思います。

Comment: @olivedesert 参照されている記事にも「RAIDコントローラ上でデータABCを2つのHDDそれぞれに複製して保存します」とあるように、RAID ではコントローラがデータを複製して保存するので、懸念されているような「壊れた側のデータをコピーしてしまう」ような事は発生しません。

Comment: 「可用性」「完全性」というキーワードで調べてください。RAIDは可用性を高めるものであり、バックアップは完全性を補完するものです。データ運用ではどちらも大切であり、データの重要性によって対応が異なります。また、データの種別、寿命によっても、テープアーカイブにするのかという判断もあります。個人ユースならばバックアップソフトを導入して、こまめに管理する方が良いと思われます。

Answer (score 4):

質問者さんの中でのバックアップの語が曖昧なのでしょう。[Wikipediaのバックアップの項](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)によると

> バックアップとは、コンピュータシステムで主にデータやシステムの状態を複製し、問題発生時の復旧（リストア）に備えることを意味する。

とあり、リストアできないRAID1はバックアップではありません。

しかし、「バックアップ」や「RAID1」といった言葉遊びは本質的ではありません。質問者さん（や閲覧者さんそれぞれ）の中で、どのような機能が必要か、より具体的にどのような場面でどのような動作を求めるか、でしかありません。

「過去にHDDの故障でデータを紛失した経験があり外付けHDDが1台故障したとしても復旧できるようにXXXしたい」であれば、**耐障害性**を求めているだけで、バックアップはその手段の１つでしかありません。バックアップではないものの耐障害性のあるRAID1で満足できるのであれば、それが答えなのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご回答中のリストアとはどのような意味でしょうか。RAID1が複数のHDDにデータをコピーしておき耐障害性を高めると結果として, 片方のHDDに問題が発生したときのリストアに備えること（バックアップ）になりませんでしょうか？rsyncを使った定期なバックアップとRAID1だとデータ同期するタイミング以外に違いが見出せませんでした。

Comment: RAID1,5,6は、一つのHDDが壊れてても、その故障HDDを交換すると、データを復旧するために、生き残ったHDDから新しく交換したHDDにデータを構築する動作をします。これがリストアです。

Comment: RAIDの欠点として、このリストア時にHDDが故障すると、全てのデータが、全滅しかねない点にあります。新品の場合、通常HDDは同じ製造ロットの場合が多く、寿命で壊れる場合、壊れる時期が同じくらいで、このリストアが非常に危険な作業になります。

Comment: また、単体製品としてのRAIDは、そのファームウェアにバグあることがあり、本来救えるデータを数パーセントのバッドセクタがあるだけで、データが復旧できないという事例も経験しました。

Answer (score 4):

RAID1とバックアップの違いが気になっているようですので、その観点を中心に回答します。

まず、バックアップとは何かという点を定義します。本回答ではISO/IEC 2382における次の定義に従うものとします。するとRAID1はこの定義に当てはまるため、**バックアップである**といえます。さらに既に廃止された規格ですが、JIS X 0008におけるバックアップの定義に従った場合もRAID1はバックアップの一手段であると解釈できます。

> **backup**
> pertaining to a procedure, technique, or hardware used to help recover lost or destroyed data or to keep a system operating

その一方で、質問中の記事や一般論などで広く用いられている意味でのバックアップは、実務上の運用方法を前提として、スナップショットをn世代分保存しておくようなものを指すことが多いという背景があり、「RAID1はバックアップとしては不十分、ないしバックアップではない」という主張が出てくることになるわけです。

このように「RAID1がバックアップかどうか」という論点は単語の解釈や言葉の使いようなどで如何様にも結論が変わるものなので、**本質ではない**と考えて差し支えないと思います。

本件で重要な点は運用する立場として、想定した構成によって要求される条件を満たせているかどうかです。これを念頭に置いて他回答を改めて読むと有益な情報を得られると思います。

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

RAID という仕組みは、如何にデータを安全に保つか = 安全性・耐障害性を高めるための仕組みであり、バックアップとは視点が違います。
確かにハード的な障害には強いかもしれないけれど、ユーザーが誤って削除したファイル等を復旧できるわけではありません。

バックアップが必要であるなら、素直に別媒体へのコピー等を検討すべきです。

外付けのHDDやNASは、「バックアップの保存先で、データが壊れては困るもの」なので RIAD 構成を取る場合が多いです。

[RAID(レイド)だからって過信は禁物！構造を理解してマメにバックアップを取ろう！](https://www.buffalo.jp/topics/trouble/detail/recovery_0005.html)

> 冗長性のあるRAIDだとしてもデータを誤って削除してしまったり、ウィルス感染、ファイルの破損等によるデータの損失は一般のパソコンや外付けHDDと同じリスクで常に存在しています。
>
> (中略)
>
> RAIDを構成したNASなどを使用していたとしても、外付けHDDなどの記憶媒体を使って定期的にバックアップを取ることが重要です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「データを誤って削除してしまったり、ウィルス感染、ファイルの破損等によるデータの損失」は外付けHDDなどの記憶媒体を使って定期的にバックアップしても起きるものではないんでしょうか？rsyncを使い定期的にバックアップを取るのとRAID1で自動で複数HDDにデータを複製することとであまり違いが見出せずでしたが、決定的な違いがあるのでしょうか

Comment: 決定的な違いとして、バックアップは復元に時間的な猶予を与えます。ポリシーによっては1週間前・1か月前の状態を保全することが可能です（これは目的次第でしょう）。一方、RAID1でのミラーは、同時に書き換えられるので、例示された人的ミス・ウイルスなどへの対策にはなり得ません。

Answer (score 3):

質問者氏の「バックアップ」と、読者の「バックアップ」の用語が使い方が違っているので混乱を招いているだけかと

- 読者一般にとってのバックアップ＝過去のファイルを復活させる手段
- 質問者氏のバックアップ＝現在ファイルの可用性・対障害性の向上のこと

ランサムウエア（デジタル身代金要求）の被害があったとき RAID では対処できない、バックアップが別途オフライン保存してあれば対処できる、という意味で RAID はバックアップの代わりになりません。 RAID1 でも RAID5 でも RAID6 でも暗号化されたデータによって上書きされちゃうからです。オンラインバックアップも暗号化されちゃったら意味がないですが、例えばウチなんかだと LTO (テープメディア) に取ったバックアップは不慮の事故で消さないように装置から外してオフライン保管していますので、こういう攻撃には「正しく運用されているバックアップ」があれば、強いはず。

あと質問者氏の訊きたいことは実はこっちなのでは？と妄想

Q1. RAID1 で片方の記憶装置だけに誤ったデータを書き込むことがあるか？
A1. 片方だけに誤ったデータを書き込むとは RAID1 カードの中で、あるいはカード→記憶装置への転送中、あるいは記憶装置の中で実媒体に書き込む際にデータが化けた場合であるはず。そういう化けが起こるとしたら RAID 構成でなくても起きるわけです。あとはその信頼性をどの程度に見積もるかだけ。 RAID1 カードという物理装置が１つ増えた分、化けの発生確率は上がっているが、実用上は発生しないと考えてよいだろうと推定してよいでしょう

Q2. RAID1 で片方の記憶装置のデータが化けている（＝物理故障と判断されないレベル）とき、どちらの結果が OS に返されるか
A2. カードの実装によるでしょうが、たいていは下記のどちらかでしょう

- 先に応答が完了した装置の応答だけが OS に返される
- RAID1 カードが定めた１台の装置の応答だけが OS に返される

実際、２台の記憶装置しかないときはどっちが**化けている**のかは誰にも判断できません（ RAID1 カードにとっても、人間にとっても）なのでこれを検出・訂正するには３台以上の記憶装置が必要です（多数決一致ではじくことができる）。３台以上の記憶装置を設置することができる状況では RAID5 に、４台以上設置可能なら RAID6 にしますので RAID1 で多数決一致判断するようなカードはまずないです。

Q3. RAID1 において片方の装置が「壊れている」とはどういうことか
A3. それはそのカード（とドライバ）の仕様次第なので、事前確認のこと
SMART 値を見ているかもしれないし READ/WRITE コマンドに対する応答時間で判断しているかもしれないし READ/WRITE コマンドに対する失敗応答を見ているかもしれないです。ハードディスク装置の壊れかけ状況では READ RETRY を数回繰り返さないと値が得られないことがあるなんてのが普通にありますが、片肺が健全ならそっちから先にデータを得られるので Q2 な状況にて対処できます。

RAID をどれだけ信頼して良いか・どのレベルの RAIDn が必要かは事前の検討が必要です。コストと可用性のバランス面で RAID1 は悪くない選択肢です。が RAID は過去ファイルを別途保存するものではないのでバックアップの代わりにはなりません。

Comment: 最近はドライブ内蔵のROM部分にウィルスが入ったりする時代なので、そこがバグってない保証もなく…というのは冗談で、一番技術的な内容に見えました。ただ同期についての説明もある方が望ましいかもしれません…

Answer (score 2):

### 先に回答

> 上の調査を元に質問があるのですが、RAID1は何等かの原因で片方のHDDが故障してデータが破損した時に、もう片方のHDDにも壊れたデータが同期されてしまうのでしょうか？

A.されません。安心してください。（ただし、壊れたデータで上書き保存してしまった場合は別です）

> 私はHDDの故障に対してのバックアップが欲しいと考えてるのですがRAID1ではバックアップになりませんか？

A.なりません。今回の要件であればRAIDのメリットは必要なさそうなので素直にバックアップを取る方がいいでしょう。
一応、RAID1でも質問者の望みは99％叶えられます。(1%については以下余談を参照ください)

### 以下余談(個人的見解)

> RAID1はバックアップにならないという記事を見かけ不安になったため質問した次第です

他の方も言及されていますが、そもそも**バックアップとRAIDでは厳密には趣旨が違う**ので混乱されているのではないでしょうか。

個人的な解釈ですが、
バックアップ「間違って作業データ消しちまった！今日の作業は消えちまったけど**昨日までのデータはバックアップしてあったから復旧できるぞ**」
・完全性重視
メリット：バックアップ済み範囲はデータが保証される（**バックアップ自体を消してしまわない限り、完全に当時の状況に戻せる**）
デメリット：バックアップ範囲外は保証できない、**故障すると復旧まで稼働できない**　←24H稼働させたいサーバーでは致命的

RAID1「相方が壊れちまった！**ここは俺が何とかするから今のうちにもう片方を交換してくれ！**」
・稼働率重視
メリット：**片方が壊れても稼働を続けられる**(その間に故障したほうを交換する)
デメリット：リアルタイム性を重視したため、**対応できるリスク範囲を削っている**(ユーザーの誤操作などの場合は対応できない。など)、**両方同時に壊れたら意味ない**

といった感じです。**絶対にデータを失いたくないからバックアップを取り**、**可能な限りシステムを止めたくないからRAIDを使う**ので、最優先事項が違うのです。

ユーザーの誤操作に対応出来ないのはRAIDでは実質的にバックアップデータ自体を同時に操作しているのと同じ状態だからです。

しかし、どちらの手法でも質問者さんの要望には応えられます。**最優先事項が違うだけで、やろうとしてることはほぼ同じなので。**
どちらのメリットを優先するかで選ばれてはどうでしょうか。